# Is there a way to pause a Python subprocess, specifically in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, resume

I have a GUI based program where I need the user to be able to pause or resume a subprocess.  For example, if I have:

```
programID = subprocess.Popen("program_name"), shell=True)
```

Is there a way that I can pause or resume this?  I read something about using SIGTERM but I didn't quite grasp it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To pause the process, use

```
os.kill(programID.pid, signal.SIGSTOP)
```

To resume execution, use

```
os.kill(programID.pid, signal.SIGCONT)
```

Comment: This looks platform dependent (i.e. depending on something Unix-like), isn't it?

Comment: @ndim: Yes, it'll work on Unix-like operating systems.  Note that the OP asked for Ubuntu.